# .htaccess to redirect a long subdomain URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Because of the way that my file structure was set up, I have folders that I don't want showing in the URL.

I want to redirect this URL:

- https://portal.domain.com/portal.domain.com/portal/test.php

To this:

- https://portal.domain.com/test

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://portal.domain.com/portal.domain.com/portal/$1 [L,NC]
```

But I get a 'too many redirects' message.

Answer (score 0):

the rewrite rule: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.domain.com`
is too generic, then:

1) the user open `https://portal.domain.com/portal.domain.com/portal/test.php`

2) the rewrite rule match and redirect to `https://portal.domain.com/test.php`

3) but when the user request the page `https://portal.domain.com/test.php`
the rewrite rule match again and will redirect the user to `https://portal.domain.com/test.php`

4,5,6,7,8,9.....) then the user opens the same page and the rewrite  rlue match again and again in an infinite loop.

Solution: the condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal.domain.com` must be less generic and not math the redirect location.

Comment: My subdomain for www.domain.com is portal.domain.com. The folder for this subdomain is also called portal.domain.com, and holds another folder called 'portal'.  I don't know how to make it less generic because I'm not able to change the folder name for the subdomain.  Can you help with some code that I could try?